# Increase pytorch transformer nhead on existing trained model

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I have trained a pytorch transformer with 4 heads, training for over a day:

```
class MyTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, nhead, num_layers, dropout):
        super(MyTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.input_linear = nn.Linear(1, d_model)
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(d_model, nhead, num_layers, dropout=dropout)

nhead=4
model = MyTransformer(d_model, nhead, num_layers, dropout=dropout)

#do training

torch.save(model, 'model.pth')
```

I was wanting to increase the nhead to 8 with the existing trained model in such a way to not start training from scratch and recommence training. Is this possible?